# ObjectId in mongoDB 2.6 not working

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using spring data mongodb in my application. It uses mongodb 2.6. I want to query documents of a collection by the id which mongo assigns during insertion. I'm doing something like this:

```
Query query = new Query();
String id = "542385a91f00bf7dbeae1fc7";
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").new Object(id));
template.find(query, entity.class);
```

This query translates to:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "542385a91f00bf7dbeae1fc7"}}
```

When I execute the same on mongo shell, it gives an error:

> error: {
>       "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $oid",
>       "code" : 17287
>   }

How do I query by id using spring data mongodb?

Comment: You can't make the query with `{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "542385a91f00bf7dbeae1fc7"}}` in mongo shell, using `{"_id":ObjectId("542385a91f00bf7dbeae1fc7")}`.

Comment: Ok. When I did SerializationUtils.serializeToJsonSafely(query), this is what it printed. So if I have to query by id, how do I do it? Because query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(new Object(id))); doesn't work. It gives me 0 result.

Comment: Could you provide the insertion java code for document, or the result of document queried from mongo shell?

Answer (score 0):

It should read

```
new ObjectId(id)
```

instead of `new Object(id)`. Please [see the API docs for details](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html).